# Eclipse SVN share project

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-indigo, subversive

I've downloaded a project from SVN repo using Tortoise SVN client. I did not download it directly inside eclipse as it was a Maven project and `.project` file was not present in the project directory. After that I created an eclipse project using mvn eclipse:eclipse and imported the project successfully inside eclipse.

Now question is I want to connect this project to SVN repo using eclipse Subversive (Currently inside eclipse its not shown as connected to any svn url). So will it be safe to connect my project using `Share Project` link ???

Comment: yeah you can share your project and then change your project and then commit it. with share your eclipse IDE connect to source control.

Comment: share my project and "change my project"? What to change man.. I did nt get it.

Comment: do you place scm setting in POM file?